# (Microsoft Sentinel - KQL) How can I use iif() or another statement to return a specific subset of results from a filter-out

Tags: kql, sentinel

Let's assume I am using Microsoft Sentinel to monitor a Windows Computer.

That computer is producing a number of Windows Alerts that all share the same general form e.g

*Windows - Account Modification(Locked)(user: #)*

*Windows - Account Modification(Unlocked)(user: #)*

*Windows - Account Modification(Password Change)(user: #)*

*Windows - Policy Change( #)*

...etc

And I want to create a query that filters out all windows events except the Policy Change. Could you help me with the syntax of the Query using **iff()** or any other similar command?

The way I had been doing it so far was to include EVERYTHING BUT the one I wanted.

so something like

**My_example_table**

**| where not ( EventName startswith "Windows - Account Modification" or EventName startswith "Windows - Computer Account" or EventName startswith "Windows - Folder Action" )**

which is both impractical as new alerts are added and inefficient as far as resources are concerned.

Again i was wondering if there is a way to filter-out things with

**not ( EventName startswith "Windows" )**

but include results with

**EventName startswith "Windows - Policy Change"**

or something of the sort

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your verbal description correctly, you only want to include events that start with `Windows - Policy Change`.

In which case, you can include *that* as the only filter:

```
T
| where EventName startswith "Windows - Policy Change"
```

In case you need the inverse (all Windows events, *except* for policy change), you can do this:

```
T
| where EventName startswith "Windows"
| where EventName !startswith "Windows - Policy Change"
```

And, in case you want to get all non-windows events, and *only* windows policy change events, you can run:

```
T
| where EventName !startswith "Windows" or
        EventName startswith "Windows - Policy Change"
```

Comment: The third one was the one I meant!!

Damn why did I not think of that! I had to modify the query a bit because for some reason !startswith does not seem to work well in my system so i used:

`| where not ( EventName startswith "Windows" ) or EventName startswith "Windows - Policy Change"`

but it works like a charm. Thanks a million m8!

EDIT: A million edits to attempt to format the response correctly and still unsuccessful :P